# Drop Table command is not working in Oracle SQL developer, it is not dropping the existing table upon using?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, ddl

```
drop Table countries;
drop Table regionss;

create TABLE regionss(
region_id NUMBER(3),
region_Name VARCHAR2(25),
CONSTRAINT regions_pk PRIMARY KEY(region_id)
);

create TABLE countriess(
country_id CHAR(2),
country_Name VARCHAR2(40),
region_id NUMBER(3),
CONSTRAINT countries_pk PRIMARY KEY(country_id),
CONSTRAINT regions_countries_fk FOREIGN KEY (region_id) REFERENCES regionss (region_id) 
);
```

I am getting these errors

```
Error starting at line : 4 in command -
create TABLE regionss(
region_id NUMBER(3),
region_Name VARCHAR2(25),
CONSTRAINT regions_pk PRIMARY KEY(region_id)
)
Error report -
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Error starting at line : 10 in command -
create TABLE countriess(
country_id CHAR(2),
country_Name VARCHAR2(40),
region_id NUMBER(3),
CONSTRAINT countries_pk PRIMARY KEY(country_id)
)
Error report -
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Isn't it s the function of Drop Command to delete the existing table given to it ? Unless I change the names of my tables, it won't work but then again upon changing the name, when I try to run the code for the second time, it gives me again the above mentioned errors.

Comment: i think your create table is failing, NOT because the table didn't get dropped, but because you're trying to create a new CONSTRAINT and one with that name already exists, CONSTRAINT regions_pk likely exists already in the REGIONS table, so change that to CONSTRAINT regionss_pk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you're dropping table `countries` and creating table `countriess`. That causes chain of errors:

- you can't drop table that doesn't exist (`countries`)
- `regionss` exists, but it has foreign key (from `coutriess`) that prevents it to be dropped.

---

```
SQL> drop Table countries;
drop Table countries
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> drop Table regionss;
drop Table regionss
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02449: unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out. I have a question that there is a  TABLES(FILTERED) folder in my Oracle SQL Developer, It has all the tables ever created on SQL Developer, Can I use drop command on them and use them ?

Comment: You're welcome. As of tables: only you know whether you still need them or not (so drop them), I can't help with that